# Poetry - can we bundle a dependency in a build?

Tags: python, python-poetry

We have an internal library. So our `pyproject.toml` looks like this:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
...
packages = [{ include = "my_package" }]

[[tool.poetry.source]]
url = "https://pypi.fury.io/<OUR_REPO>/"
name = "fury"
secondary = true

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8.10"
some-internal-lib = "^1"
...
```

If we `poetry build`, the `some-internal-lib` is not included.

Can we include it in some way in the built wheel?

---

More details:

We cannot access the internal repo in our specific use case, so it should be bundled and sent together to the target runtime.
I am looking for a "java/scala uber jar", but only including the specific internal dependency inside the wheel.

Comment: With Poetry or not: this is probably feasible, but it is not trivial. This is usually referred as "vendoring", you can look this term up for some info about this (and potential solutions). But first I want to note that vendoring is quite frowned upon in the Python packaging ecosystem, this is considered a bad practice. -- On the other hand, maybe this is a "X Y problem", you think you need to "bundle" but there are actually better more straightforward solutions. Maybe building a "wheelhouse" that can be uploaded to the target machine(s), is a better solution.